# Exporting result of select statement to CSV format

Tags: oracle, csv, export

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create an Excel Spreadsheet from a Oracle Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017863/create-an-excel-spreadsheet-from-a-oracle-database)

how can i export result of select statement to CSV format in oracle, please in pl/sql
thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you use a tool like sql developer, or toad, or SqlNavigator you have option for saving the results of a query. 
If you use sqlplus, you can use spool command.( [How do I spool to a CSV formatted file using SQLPLUS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643137/how-do-i-spool-to-a-csv-formatted-file-using-sqlplus)) 
What's your case?

Comment: i have toad; but it's an automated query (batch) i want to save the result on csv file

Comment: ok, so you can use the link from my response, if the batch is run with sqlplus. Isn't it?