# How can I make owa_sylk generate the output with a special encoding like ANSI?

Tags: oracle, excel, plsql

I want to know whether it is possible to tell owa_sylk to generate the Excel file (output) with a special encoding. I have some problems with Chinese characters.

Can we solve this problem in other way? For example, converting the encoding after creating the output?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine solved this issue. We need just to convert the encoding with the help of following code in the body of owa_sylk:

owa_sylk.print_rows change p( line ); on p(convert(line, 'ZHS32GB18030','AL32UTF8'));

Answer (score 1):

SYLK is a venerable interface, and pre-dates Unicode.  It is also a proprietary Microsoft implementation. They don't publish a spec.  So implementations like ORA_SYLK are basically reversed engineered.

Anyway, [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYmbolic_LinK_%28SYLK%29):

> "even if a SYLK file is created by an application that supports
>   Unicode (for example Microsoft Excel), the SYLK file will be encoded
>   in the current system's ANSI code page, not in Unicode. If the
>   application contained characters that were displayable in Unicode but
>   have no codepoint in the current system's code page, they will be
>   converted to question marks ('?') in the SYLK file."

So there doesn't seem to be much you can with ORA_SYLK because the fault lies with SYLK.  There are some other ways of exporting data to Excel; they may be able to solve your problem.  I provided links at the end of my answer to another question.  [Find out more.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6018606/146325)